# cloning an amazon machine instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two amazon machine instances running.Both of them are m3.xlarge instances. One of them has the right software and configuration that I want to use.I want to create a snapshot of the EBS volume for that machine and use that as the EBS volue to boot the second machine from. Can I do that and expect it to work without shutting down the first machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well described in the AWS [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html)...

"You can take a snapshot of an attached volume that is in use. However, snapshots only capture data that has been written to your Amazon EBS volume at the time the snapshot command is issued. This might exclude any data that has been cached by any applications or the operating system. If you can pause any file writes to the volume long enough to take a snapshot, your snapshot should be complete. However, if you can't pause all file writes to the volume, you should unmount the volume from within the instance, issue the snapshot command, and then remount the volume to ensure a consistent and complete snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

I have amazon as well, with 3 different clusters.  With one of my clusters after setting up 25 of them I realized there was a small issue in the configuration and had live traffic going to them so I couldn't' shut down.

You can snapshot the first machines volume while it's still running, I had to do this myself.  It took a little while, but ultimately it worked out.  Please note that amazon cannot guarantee the consistency of the disk when doing this.

I did a snapshot of the entire thing, fixed what needed to be fixed, and spooled up 25 new servers and terminated the other 25 ( easier than modifying volumes, etc )..  But you can create a new volume with the new snapshot, and attach it to an instance and do what needs to be done to get it to boot off that volume without much of a headache.

Being that I went the easy route of spooling up new instances after my snapshot was complete, I can't walk you through on how to get a running instance to boot off a new volume.

Comment: do I have to make an AMI from the snapshot ? Some documents seems to suggest this approach.

Comment: @liv2hak yes it will create an AMI which you can then attach to an EBS volume.